# How to check TCP sequence number to detect mitm?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, windows-10, ubuntu

I suspect that my router (I'm using an iPhone as router) has been owned and the attacker is making some kind of mitm attack. I suspect also that some html and js code has not been sent to my laptop and filtered by the attacker, meaning that some sites do not have some functionalities.

If this is true, then there should be a hole in the TCP sequence number stream. How can I check the TCP sequence number integrity?

I'm using a Windows 10 VM in a Linux/ubuntu host with VirtualBox. My idea is to check the sequence number with snort or Wireshark from the host, but I'd appreciate some hint on alternatives.

Comment: If you are using HTTPS to access the websites, then MitM detection is already built into browsers.

Comment: yes, I use https but I suspect that the attacker is able to decrypt the stream. I don't know how.

Comment: If you are not getting some files from a site, it is likely a bug in your phone, not an attack.

Comment: You seem to suspect a lot of things, but you haven't provided any reason why you would suspect them. Why do you suspect you are being MiTMed in the first place?

Comment: This is a classic X/Y problem. You assume the phone is compromised, you have an idea about sequence numbers, then you want to know about sequence numbers to identify the compromise. But you have not confirmed that sequence numbers are relevant to your use case. Instead, why not focus on the compromise and not your one, niche, and highly specific technical idea you have?

Comment: @nobody everyday there is a leak of information about my browsing. Also I found the phone totally discarged and powered of just in one night when the day before was totally 100% charged. Usually I find the phone 100% charged in the morning. Also please English is not my native language so that it's pretty difficult to explain what succeed in my everyday life to show you why I absolutely know that my phone iwas been hacking. The guy know what I buy on amazon, everytime or what I say in a private chat on facebook. Also he can manipulate the adv that receive my pc.

Comment: @nobody I think you should believe me because you're not in my life, you don't see what's happening here. You can't ask me an explanation because it's too difficult for me to explain the connection betwheen facts that happens in my life and things that happens online. So I think you should believe me and just answer my questions.

Comment: @schroeder I'm not focusing on iphone compromise because make a forensics analysis of an iphone is more difficult to me and I find more easy detect the attack to my pc. I don't know anything about iphone, but I know pretty well linux.

Comment: If you believe there is a compromise of the phone, then factory reset the phone. Why go through all this work that you are not sure will even meet your needs?

Comment: Your history here for over a year and a half is about your assertion that your phone is somehow compromised. People have been saying the same thing for over a year: you are misinterpreting events in your life.

Comment: @schroeder it's hard for me to explain myself in english. I'm making assumptions to explain what's going on. So I'm ruling out the various solutions as I get new information on what's going on.
I live in Italy and my country is very different from the united states, here there is a mafia culture and things never happen in the light of the sun. You say that I am misinterpreting events about my life and you, from there   I don't know where you live, think you are interpreting correctly what is happening here?
You don't know nothing and you claim to know much more about my life than me.

Comment: as you can see my nickname is BiosRootkit because more than 1 year ago I thought that that attacker was using a biosrootkit, now I know that this is not true. My hypothesis now is that that attacker has own the router and from ther is making a fileless attack to my laptop.

Comment: but I don't think the laptop is compromised... I know who is the attacker. I know him.

Comment: With 1.5 years of data from you, it's clear you are making assumptions without clear evidence and you are posting X/Y problems. You have been living with this for 1.5 years without doing what you need to do: get someone to investigate. If someone has the access you claim they have, your digitlal life is completely compromised. And all they do (so you claim) is merely to tell you that they "know things". That's not what an attacker does, You need to get an expert to actually look at your devices to confirm the compromise.

Comment: The story is much more long, I'm living this nightmare since 20 years. Anyway if you have some advice, I mean some foresnics analyser that can help me please gimme the name or  the url so that I can contact him. 
it is not prudent to contact an Italian technician because most Italians are prone to corruption and it would be very easy for the attacker to bribe the coach in order not to let the truth out. This thing has already happened. I contacted kaspersky but they work only for enterprises and not private citizen.

Comment: I need someone outside italy. The best would be someone in UK or Germany.

Answer (score 3):

> If this is true there should be a hole in the tcp sequence number stream.

MITM attacks don't leave such holes. Your approach to detect MITM thus would not even work in theory and there is no need to discuss how to make in work in practice then.

TCP sequence numbers describe a  position in the byte stream (not the packet number). The recipient reassembles the stream based on the sequence numbers. A "hole" in the stream would result the in a broken connection, i.e. would simply not work.

Some MITM attacks are packet based and only change the content of a single packet at a time. In this case they don't change the length of the packet, but just some bytes inside. Usually MITM attacks are applied to the connection itself, i.e. they essentially create a new connection with new sequence numbers. The original connection is never seen by the recipient. In this case arbitrary modifications to the data can be made, including adding or removing data. With both approaches the TCP sequence numbers are "complete", i.e. there are no holes in the stream.